# Identification of reduced row echelon form and nuance in Gauss-Jordan elimination technique

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

I'm studying *Linear Algebra: Step By Step* by Kuldeep Singh, and on page 23 he shows this as an example of a matrix in *reduced row echelon* form:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 & 8 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

My questions:

1. Why doesn't the "8" in the first row disqualify it from being called *reduced* ?  Is it a typo?
2. If I wanted to reduce this by converting the "8" to "0", how would I accomplish that?  The Gauss-Jordan elimination technique he showed involves multiplying another row so that it also contains an "8" in the same spot, then subtracting.  But since the other rows all have zeros in that column, I'm not sure how I would apply this technique here.

Comment: In short: $8$ is not a typo. There is no way to convert the $8$ to a $0$ in this case via row operations. However, even if the entry immediately below it were non-zero (and the remaining entries were the same), converting the $8$ to a $0$ would necessarily take the matrix out of reduced row echelon form.

Comment: No, that is not a typo. Elementary row operations only allow you to switch rows, add a multiple of one row to the other, or multiple a row by a *nonzero* number. Can you see how all three operations will not ever make that a zero? The matrix has been reduced.

Comment: @twosigma Indeed, that's what was confusing me -- thanks for clarifying.  I had thought it had to be all zeros other than the 1 and the last column, but I see now that was a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Yes. On a related note, you may learn about leading variables, free variables, pivots etc. soon, if you haven't already. Or you can look them up.

Comment: Any column _that has a pivot_ must have zeros above and below the pivot. Non-pivot columns can have anything at all in rows that have pivots.

Comment: To clarify what I meant by "will not ever make that a zero": obviously we could make the position of the matrix in which the 8 is currently in turn into a 0, e.g. by exchanging rows. But what I meant was that you can't make that *column* into all 0's.